# XMLHTTPRequest completes but throws error message under PhoneGap and IOS 8 "Connection Failed"

Tags: cordova, xmlhttprequest, ios8

Anyone seen the ***"Connection Failed"*** message with a PhoneGap application running under the new IOS 8 while making an XMLHTTPRequest that takes longer than 10ms?  I have an app that works fine under IOS 7 with the caveat that in XCode I can see the Thread warning messages but at least it does not throw up a dialog for every call that the user has to close to continue all the while it has already updated the UI behind the popup dialog.  I get the ***THREAD WARNING: ['Notification'] took '31.723145' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.***
but not sure if there is anything that can be done, I'm just using the standard XMLHTTPRequest async call.

Comment: maybe similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25939391/ajax-error-after-upgrading-from-ios7-to-ios8) issue.

Comment: What version of cordova is the project using? Per comments from Cordova today, you have to be on 3.6 for iOS8

Comment: Oh did not know that Thank You.  I'm using 3.4 currently but the XMLHTTPRequest not sure if that is Cordova or from the base Web Class.

Comment: I did the npm install but only installed 3.5  I manually did the download for 3.6.3 but it too still shows the popups as well as the warnings in the console about needing to run the thread in the background